# Accessing MCP4451 Digital Pot with STM32 using HAL for i2c?

Tags: stm32, hal-library

I am using an STM32 NUCLEO-F042K6 dev board to interact with a MCP4451 digital pot. I want to be able to adjust the wiper values through i2c. I am using the STM32CubeIDE and the HAL library to interface.

```
 static const uint8_t POT_ADDRESS = 0x58;
 static const uint8_t INCREMENT = 0x94;

  while (1) {
  buf[0] = INCREMENT;
  ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, POT_ADDRESS, buf, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  if (ret != HAL_OK) {
      strcpy((char*)buf, "Error Tx\r\n");
  } else {
      strcpy((char*)buf, "YEET\r\n");
  }

  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, buf, strlen((char*)buf), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

  HAL_Delay(200);
  }
```

I have the correct configuration, but I keep getting "Error Tx" on the serial monitor. I made sure to power the i2c lines with pull-up resistors to 3.3V. I'm a bit lost as to what to do.

Comment: Debug by looking at the condition `if (ret != HAL_OK) { strcpy((char*)buf, "Error Tx\r\n");` What does that tell you?

Comment: What value pull-up resistors did you use?

Comment: Potentially your address is wrong for following reason : 1. The address set bits are wrong ?

Comment: @RonBeyer I used 2.7k resistors

Comment: Why did you not test what the result is? It will tell you if the I2C device responds with a NAK, or with a timeout if the bus is jammed. Are you sure you set the A0 and A1 pins pulled down so that the address really is set to 0x58? If A0 and A1 are floating, they have pull-ups so out of reset the address would be 0x5E. Is the chip reset properly, and released from reset before communicating with it?

Comment: @ManojKumar: I'm actually sending this command to a line of digital pots, each with different addresses. Since there's only two address bits, and the line has 4 pots, each with different configured address bits, i2c should be able to communicate to at least one of them.

Comment: @KingDuken I'm not sure I know what you mean. I ran the code on the dev board, and since i'm getting "Error Tx", the HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit function did not return the HAL_OK. I'm assuming this means communication over i2C failed

Comment: @Justme Could you elaborate over how I should test the result? I did run the code, and receive the "Error Tx" message. The address pins have internal pullups. Also, I'm not sure about the reset or how to go about that

Comment: @koreamaniac101 If the result is not HAL_OK, then it is something else. It will be easiest to just open the I2C HAL code and see what possible return values there are, but most likely there will be HAL_BUSY, HAL_ERROR or HAL_TIMEOUT, and for the case of error, the I2C instance contains an ErrorCode you can get for further info. It is difficult to say anything specific as each STM32 has wildly different I2C peripherals and HAL libraries for it. It is also worth to check SDA and SCL are connected the right way around, so that they are not swapped.

Comment: Debugging from a software point of view, if you understand the conditions behind your `if` statement, you should be able to point out what went wrong. You can read what `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit` needs and compare it to `HAL_OK`. Also in regards to what Justme said, check your pins on slave device to verify that your address pins match what you code says. Review the datasheet of your slave device.

Comment: @Justme Thank you for the advice. I rewrote my if statement to check for all the return conditions. The function returns HAL_ERROR, and using the HAL_I2C_GetError() function, I was able to get an error code of 4, which corresponds to an AF (Acknowledgement Failure) error. Any ideas where to go from here?

Comment: Has the I2C been initialized? GPIO ports configured properly? Clocks enabled for peripherals? That code does not show any of these things.

Comment: @Justme Thanks for the help! I did configure everything correctly in software. However, my supervisor found the issue. The digital pot runs off of 5V, but since the i2c line runs at 3.3V, it wasn't registering digital high properly. Since the STM32 pins on my dev board are 5V, as soon as I ran everything on 5V, I got an ok status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My supervisor found the issue. The digital pot runs off of 5V, but since the i2c line runs at 3.3V, it wasn't registering digital high properly. Since the STM32 pins on my dev board are 5V, as soon as I ran everything on 5V, I got an ok status.